# How to get value of a variable?

Tags: javascript, console.log

I am trying to figure out a script that adds 1 each time it runs to a variable, **then** console logs the total amount of times.

```
for (let i = 1; i <= limitFizzBuzz; i++) {
// Count the FizzBuzzes
let amountOfFizzBuzzes;
amountOfFizzBuzzes = amountOfFizzBuzzes += 1;
console.log(amountOfFizzBuzzes);
}
```

When I tried to run this in a loop, I get:
[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `amountOfFizzBuzzes` starts out `undefined`. What do you expect subtracting 1 from `undefined` to give you? (nothing useful)

Comment: `console.log(undefined + 1) // NaN`. Start from `0`, not from `undefined` (which is what `let amountOfFizzBuzzes` assigns). Also initialize the variable outside the loop, otherwise you're reinitializing it in each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a simpler version of the first problem:

```js
let num;
num += 1;
console.log(num);
```

- `num += 1` is a correct statement that adds `1` to the value of `num` and stores the result back in `num`.
- `console.log(num);` is a correct statement that writes the value of `num` to the console.
- But `let num;` doesn’t give a starting value for `num`. When a variable isn’t initialized to a value in JavaScript, it gets the value `undefined`. Doing math on `undefined` as if it were a number results in `NaN`, which is what you see.

So, a fixed version of the simpler code gives an initial value to `num`, like zero:

```js
let num = 0;
num += 1;
console.log(num);
```

---

The next issue is scope. If you declare a variable inside the loop, it’s a new variable each time around. Instead, you want to use the *same* variable for every iteration, and have it keep its value, so move the declaration outside:

```js
let amountOfFizzBuzzes = 0;

for (let i = 1; i <= limitFizzBuzz; i++) {
    amountOfFizzBuzzes += 1;
    console.log(amountOfFizzBuzzes);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I see the important of scope in back-end coding. I trying to get better at the back-end side of coding. This is more helpful than the top answer because its explains more details.

Answer (score 0):

first you  Define a var `let amountOfFizzBuzzes;`  inside a loop  so that should be outside the loop
second if you need to increment a number this is a right way to do it

```
let amountOfFizzBuzzes=0;
for (let i = 1; i <=limitFizzBuzz; i++) {
// Count the FizzBuzzes
amountOfFizzBuzzes+= 1;
console.log(amountOfFizzBuzzes);
}
```

.

.

```js
//....
limitFizzBuzz = 5;


//if you want to start from zero & increment it X times
let amountOfFizzBuzzes = 0;
for (let i = 1; i <= limitFizzBuzz; i++) {
  // Count the FizzBuzzes
  amountOfFizzBuzzes += 1;
  console.log(amountOfFizzBuzzes);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I see the important of scope in back-end coding.  I trying to get better at the back-end side of coding.

Answer (score -1):

@Morrison is absolutely correct.
Just initialize your **amountOfFizzBuzzes** above the for loop.

```
let amountOfFizzBuzzes =0;
for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
// Count the FizzBuzzes
 amountOfFizzBuzzes++;
//amountOfFizzBuzzes +=1;
console.log(amountOfFizzBuzzes);
}
```